# How to change a subreport at runtime in rdlc report?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

I created Main report named "ReportMain.rdlc". Inside this main report added subreport.

**Main Report**

[image]

I have a lot of subreport but I need to select only one subreport for showing in a Main report.
So I need to set subreport path by dynamically.
For example, I have  three subreports  such as "ReportSub1.rdlc", "ReportSub2.rdlc" and "ReportSub3.rdlc". I made a condition for selecting subreport by these code.

```
        If (strReport == "1") Then {
            m_LocalReport.LoadSubreportDefinition("MySubreport", File.OpenRead("Reports/ReportSub1.rdlc"))
        }else if (strReport == "2"){
            m_LocalReport.LoadSubreportDefinition("MySubreport", File.OpenRead("Reports/ReportSub2.rdlc"))
        }else if (strReport == "3"){
            m_LocalReport.LoadSubreportDefinition("MySubreport", File.OpenRead("Reports/ReportSub3.rdlc"))
        }
```

But I don't know how to set **Use this report as a report:** in designer.

[image]

I want to set at runtime. What should I input to this box?

(I've ever added all subreport and set hide or visible. This way is work. But I have a lot of subreport. A main report will create all subreports although it was hidden. So a rendering is very slow performance.)

Comment: Is it mandatory to fill this 'Use this report as a subreport'?

Comment: Yes. If I don't input any value, it will error like these "The ReportName for the subreport ‘MySubreport’ is not valid. A ReportName can not be an empty string or just white space."